Extract only phone number without country code in BigQuery
I have some data in GCP BigQuery where the 'phone_number' column is in the formats shown below. How can I extract only the digits in the data corresponding to the area code and subsequent phone number, and only where the country code is +1?
phone_number
+1 414-935-5896
+1 (408) 832-3423
+91 90353 45657

What I want:
US_phone_number_only
4149355896
4088323423
NULL


Hi - please update your question with the SQL that you’ve managed to write so far and explain the specific issue you are facing

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE for extracting only numbers from your string column, then combine with a case expression for determining which rows need treatment.
with my_data as (
  select '+1 414-935-5896' as phone union all
  select '+1 (408) 832-3423' union all
  select '+91 90353 45657'
)
select 
 phone, 
 case
  when left(phone, 3) = '+1 ' then right(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone,'[^0-9]',''), 10) 
  --else null
 end as phone2
from my_data

Output:



phone
phone2




+1 414-935-5896
4149355896


+1 (408) 832-3423
4088323423


+91 90353 45657
null



